# SSRS Element Path not returning any columns

Tags: xml, reporting-services, path, element

I am developing a report that has a web service as a dataset. I have the service returning a serialized dataset and am having some trouble getting the right ElementPath to work. I've read the pages on XML particularly 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/element-path-syntax-for-xml-report-data-ssrs, but to no avail.

My data looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   <soap:Body>
    <GetAxisMeasuresResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetAxisMeasuresResult>
        <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
          <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="AxisMeasurement">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="Axis" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="Average" type="xs:float" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="Range" type="xs:float" minOccurs="0" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
          <NewDataSet xmlns="">
            <AxisMeasurement diffgr:id="AxisMeasurement1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
              <Axis>0</Axis>
              <Average>3.71116638</Average>
              <Range>0.0333445072</Range>
            </AxisMeasurement>
            <AxisMeasurement diffgr:id="AxisMeasurement2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
              <Axis>1</Axis>
              <Average>1.66359055</Average>
              <Range>0.09599972</Range>
            </AxisMeasurement>
```

And my SSRS query and Element path look something like this:

```
<Query>
<Method Namespace="http://tempuri.org/" Name="GetAxisMeasures">
</Method>
<SoapAction>http://tempuri.org/GetAxisMeasures</SoapAction>
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespace="false"> 
   GetAxisMeasuresResponse {}/GetAxisMeasuresResult {}/diffgram {}/NewDataSet {}/AxisMeasurement{Axis, Average, Range}
</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Now when I execute the query through the report, I don't get any columns back at all. Its as if the report doesn't get a result set back. However if I remove the path and just return the defaults, I get the three elements defined in the schema at the top of the result set.

All I am trying to do is to get the three columns Axis, Average, and Range to appear in the Report data pane so I can actually display them on the report.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Just wanted to note I have tried  <ElementPath IgnoreNamespace="true"> but still get the same result.

Comment: Made some progress on this I have been to get the column names to show up by including the http://tempuri.org namespace to my ElementPath. That allows me to add whatever columns I choose. Unfortunately none of the data seems to be coming through. A step in the right direction but far from complete.